# FullCalendar - Disable/Block out times on certain days

Tags: fullcalendar

Im looking for some advice, options and examples if I wanted to block out/disable certain times on certain days.
For example, if I have the schedule on day/week view and say a business books appointments from 9 - 5 mon - friday, but on sat then are open 8 - 4 how can I represent this on the view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need two things for that.

First, set up business hours in fullcalendar constructor. Then, add a function to prevent drag and dropping events to wrong dates.

```
$("#c").fullCalendar({
...
businessHours: { start: '09:00', end: '17:00', dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },
eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
            eventDropOrResizeHandler(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view);
        },
eventResize: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
            eventDropOrResizeHandler(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view);
        }
});


function eventDropOrResizeHandler(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    // check that event.start and event.end are within limits, and if not, call revertFunc();
}
```

Finally, you should add the same check that event.start and event.end are within limits into your function that allows user to create/edit events.